# Float Dataframe to string txt file

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a trouble to change the dataframe(float) to string as dat file.
My df is bellow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foXwa.png)

using this code to save the dataframe as txt,
np.savetxt('foil 5.txt', df.values, fmt='%d')
and runing the file, the string mode change the float to integer and retorn a file with only zero value.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvsVt.png)

But i need that this file stay with the same picture bellow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWknQ.png)

If someone already fix this issue, please, share with me the process

Comment: Please provide sample data as text, not image. It is more convenient that way.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at `to_csv()` and `read_csv()` these functions will save the data in a format that is txt readable and keep strings as strings and floats as floats.

Comment: Thank you!   

I already save as csv like(df.to_csv('FOIL 1.csv') ) but after save as csv the delimiter is "," and stay with the first column and the line x, y. 

To run this file, the file format need stay like the last picture send.

Comment: In that case use `df.to_csv('filename.txt', sep=' ')` which will keep the format the same but use space as the separator.

Comment: it worked @Paul Brennan, Thank You very much. 
I already removed the header with this command "df.to_csv ('foil T.txt', sep = '', header = None, index = None)" but the first column with the data frame number sequence is still missing, is it a parameter that I'm forgetting to insert as well?

Comment: `df.to_csv('filename.txt', sep=' ', index=False)` or `df.to_csv('filename.txt', sep=' ', index=True)` should put the index numbers in the file